# Let $M$ be a compact metric space and $F:M\to M$ be a function that preserves distances, prove that is an homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $(M, d)$ is a metric space, $M$ is compact and $F: M\to M$ preserves distances (that is to say, $d(x,y)=d(F(x),F(y)) \ \forall x,y\in M$), then it must be proven that $F$ is an homeomorphism.

Because $M$ is compact and is Hausdorff (since it's a metric space), if $F$ is continuous and bijective then it's an homeomorphism.

I have already proven the continuity and injectivity from the preservation of distances, but I'm not sure how to prove exhaustivity.